# Google Guice - Singleton with param

Tags: java, dependency-injection, singleton, guice

I started using google guice and trying to create an singleton object.  Not sure how to pass the parameter required by getClient(...) and create an object using @Inject annotation.  Any help is appreciated.

```
public class Client
{
    private readonly Child _child;
    public Client(Child child)
    {
        this._child = child;
    }

    static class NestedClass {
        public String propX;
        public String propY;    
    }
}

class MyHelperModule extends AbstractModule {
    private static final String propXValue = "hello";

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    private Client getClient(
        String propY) {

       Client.NestedClass nestedClass = new Client.NestedClass();
       nestedClass.propX("hello");
       nestedClass.propY(propY);

       return new Client(nestedClass);
    }
}


// helper class to create singleton object Client.  
// Need to pass param propY while creating the instance
public Client _client;

@Inject
void newClient(Client client) {
    this._client = client;
}
```

Thanks
Srini

Comment: What do you expect the end result to be? A Client for each different property. Or just an new Client instance for each call? 

For me: As is, I would involve Guice here? Call the .getClient() method with the parameter you need, and you get a new instance with that parameter set.

Comment: I need to create a single instance of getClient for propY and need to get this instance using guice @inject annotation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments to a `@Provides` methods are obtained through bindings in Guice. Typically you shouldn't bind something as common as a `String` without a [binding annotation](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations). So something like this should let the `Client` be created:

```
@BindingAnnotation
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@interface PropX {}

// ...

bind(String.class).annotatedWith(PropX.class).toInstance("propX value");
```